# MySQL rollback on transaction with lost/disconnected connection

Tags: mysql, transactions, timeout, rollback, disconnect

I need to make MySQL server to rollback transaction immediately after its client disconnected, because each client works concurrently. The problem can be reproduced like these (using an innodb table type)

On Client A:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tblone FOR UPDATE;
#... then disconnect your connection to the server
```

On Client B:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tblone FOR UPDATE;
#... lock wait time out will occur here
```

I had set MySQL's server option like `innodb_rollback_on_timeout` and using mysql's client `mysql --skip-reconnect` on both client. I tried this using one server and two client, on a network. I disconnected the network physically (unplug the cable) after `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;` line. I need to make other clients to be able to use `tblone` on a transaction (lock it, update it) immediately, and for that to happen I think the server should rollback the transaction for Client A, after Client A disconnects.

Comment: Interesting question. I thought this is automatic! So we need something like `innodb_rollback_on_disconnect`.. that would be great and I'd say, that should be the default! That would be reasonable change request for mysql.

Comment: @Tomas I hit the same problem after this question was first asked in 2012! I wrote a simple python script to emulate the question and found the second client immediately got the lock if the first client lost the connection. But I don't understand how MySQL does that, please refer to github.com/qiulang/mysql

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you are physically disconnecting a client you're not sending a normal disconnect (which would have caused a rollback) and the MySQL protocol isn't very chatty so the server never knows that the client isn't there. I think this is a flaw in the protocol when comparing to other database systems where the client and server talks internally much more.

Anyway. There are two variables that you could change. They basically do the same but for different clients.

The first is [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and it is used by application clients like java or php.

The other is [interactive_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout) and it is used by the mysql client (as in your tests)

In both cases the server to kills the connection after a number of seconds and when doing so rollbacks all transactions and releases all locks.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, and I have tried using both option, and set them to 60 seconds (for experiment), but another problem arise. After 60 seconds of inactivity (idle) the connection automatically closed, and the next query produced an error (server has gone away) and then automatically reconnect. Do I need to code something to query every 59s to make sure the connection alive? Or is there another way? Is a long query that takes more than 60s will get disconnected in the middle of the process?

Comment: Because I only need this behavior while in transaction, can I do something like `SET SESSION wait_timeout = 60` just before transaction and restore it after a commit/rollback?

Comment: You should be able to change it within your stored procedure or as a separate statement before you start a transaction.

And you are right about the idle connection being closed. That is how it works. However, long running queries doesn't count as "idle" as far as I've seen so that should be safe (easy to test with `select 1, sleep(61) from dual`)

Comment: Wow thanks, so I just set `SET @old_wait_timeout := @@session.wait_timeout; SET @@session.wait_timeout := 60;` just before `START TRANSACTION;` and then restore it after a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` using `SET @@session.wait_timeout := @old_wait_timeout;`. I hope this works

Comment: @qsoft My understand: wait_timeout is a inactive timeout. Means it will be cleared and restart after every activation, e.g: table scan, row insert, network package received, and etc. So under a transaction, we can set this option to a smaller value (e.g.: 5 seconds). That would be more suitable for error detection and failure recovery.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand my case is the first client crashes unexpectedly (due to bug in it) is it the same  physically disconnecting a client from mysql point of view ? Do I need to wait `wait_timeout` before the first transaction to be rollback ?

Comment: @Qiulang - My Answer hopefully addresses your last Comment.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand In both cases the server to kills the connection after a number of seconds and when doing so rollbacks all transactions and releases all locks. -> Any corresponding statement in mysql docs?

Answer (score 3):

This is to discuss some of the Comments.  Please note that this disagrees with some of the Comments.  I'll use an INSERT instead of SELECT..FOR UPDATE because the effect is more visible.

Let's look at some different cases:

(1) No SQL + timeout

```
START TRANSACTION;
do some SQL statement(s)
do no SQL for more than the timeout (before COMMITing)
```

Avoid this because of the cases detailed below.  Solution:  Don't depend on InnoDB to help you with long transactions.

(2) long-running query

```
START TRANSACTION;
do some SQL statement(s)
run an SQL query that takes more than the timeout
COMMIT;
```

All is well.  The timeout does not apply as long as the server (mysqld) is continuing to perform queries.  That is, the timeout 'clock' starts over at the end of each SQL statement

(3) (auto-reconnect)

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT ... VALUES (123);
    time passes; no SQL performed for longer than the timeout
    disconnect occurs
INSERT ... VALUES (456);
    auto-reconnect (because you have it ENabled);
    the INSERT proceeds
COMMIT;
```

123 will be rolled back; 456 will be inserted.  (Similarly SELECT..FOR UPDATE would lose the locks.)  Not good.  The solution is to turn off "auto-reconnect".  Instead, check for errors and treat the disconnect error as a fatal error for the Transaction.  (Then start over the transaction.)

The INSERT 456 will be running in a new transaction, controlled by `autocommit`.

(4) (NO auto-reconnect)

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT ... VALUES (123);
    time passes; no SQL for longer than the timeout
    disconnect occurs
INSERT ... VALUES (456);
    NO auto-reconnect (because you have it DISabled)
COMMIT;
```

123 will be rolled back.  The INSERT of 456 will get an error something like "connection lost".  Start the transaction over.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I probably need to point out that what you described here is more likely happened with mysql client not with a running program. Your answer serves more for a DBA problem than for a programming problem. BTW, the default value for wait_timeout is 8 hours. I feel it is too long for a running thread/process

Comment: It should be `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`, which defaults to 50 seconds.

Comment: I will write some code to verify it. It should be easy to verify.

Comment: Hi I wrote a simple python script to test our discussion. But to my surprise when the first process returns without closing the DB connection explicitly (to emulate crash),the 2nd process always notice immediately. Can you take a look ? https://github.com/qiulang/mysql

Comment: @Qiulang - I don't see anything equivalent to `START TRANSACTION` in the `crash_test.py`

Comment: Hi I think the transaction is started automatically (by mysql driver) so I just to call commit(). I will double check that.

Comment: Hi please refer to here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52723551/301513

Comment: @Qiulang - I have some quibbles with the Answer in that SO; I added another Answer.  That Q&A does not deal with auto-reconnect; your Q and my A (here) does deal with it.

Comment: But regarding to my code, were you concerned that doesn't actually use a transaction ?  From my experience and from what I see I think it starts a transaction. But my question is when the 1st process holds the lock doesn't close the connection, the 2nd process gets the lock immediately. How can the 2nd process get the lock?

Comment: @Qiulang - There are (at least) two kinds of locks.  The stronger one is "exclusive" (`X`); it prevents reads and writes.  Search for `mysql locks exclusive shared intention read write`

Comment: OK I found https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-shared-exclusive-locks here ”SELECT ... FOR UPDATE sets an intention exclusive lock“. If it is an ix lock then I can't understand what I saw.

Comment: BTW, it is easy to observe innodb_lock_wait_timeout from script that is another reason I believe they are run in a transaction.

Comment: @Qiulang - Since innodb_lock_wait_timeout can be set as GLOBAL and SESSION, you can't actually see the value in effect anywhere but your own connection.  (Sure, it is rare for anyone ot change that setting.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233532/discussion-between-qiulang-and-rick-james).