# Mysql innodb row lock doesn't work

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb, rows

Iam using mysql v5.6 .

When i send the following mysql query using php which will select some rows also locking them:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
```

I get the following error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your Mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2
```

Thanks

Comment: The error message is about error in LIMIT and you don't have LIMIT in the query that you show, so please show the original query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mysql innodb row lock doesn't work**

Now, I think its problem is you should not use the `transaction not started` that only make big different so, you should must `START TRANSACTION` like my code, and

some times it was happens when in a running `transaction`, two identical statements get different values, because some other transaction has modified the table’s rows.

**like your as following as:**

```
transaction1> START TRANSACTION;
transaction1> SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE;
```

**For example:**

```
transaction1> SELECT first_name, last_name FROM customer WHERE id = 3 FOR UPDATE;

+------------+-----------+
| first_name | last_name |
+------------+-----------+
| JMAIL      | KRISH     |
+------------+-----------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**you should refer this link:**

***http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/03/27/innodbs-gap-locks/***

***http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locks-set.html***

***https://stackoverflow.com/a/22007412/3242978***

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB implements standard `row-level locking` where there are two types of locks, `shared (S) locks` and `exclusive (X) locks`.

`A shared (S) lock permits a transaction to read a row.
An exclusive (X) lock permits a transaction to update or delete a row.`

Locking of rows for update using `SELECT FOR UPDATE` only applies when `autocommit` is disabled (either by beginning transaction with `START TRANSACTION` or by setting `autocommit` to `0`. If autocommit is enabled, the rows matching the specification are not locked. 
Refer link

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-lock-modes.html