# MySQL Connector/Python: How to use the start_transaction() method?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to access some records using MySQL Connector/Python but I am unable to understand how `start_transaction()` is used.

I would be great if someone could shed some light on uses cases where it is required.

Update: After reading the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-start-transaction.html) carefully it looks like, the `start_transaction()` method is only required when `autocommit=True`. Is that true? I am still confused over this and documentation doesn't provide any examples.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you normally use the [`connection.start_transaction()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-start-transaction.html) method to  start a transaction when the autocommit feature is enabled.

Since MySQL Connector/Python is [Python DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)-compliant, autocommit is disabled by default and the first SQL statement will implicitly begin a transaction. You must call [`connection.commit`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) to commit the transaction.

Comment: This means that `start_transaction()` is only useful when `autocommit=True`. Am I right? or Can I use it when `autocommit=False`?

Comment: You can use it with `autocommit=False` as well if you want to be more explicit.  It may also be useful when you need to change the default transaction options.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, there are 3 ways of doing transactions:

1. Explicit.  Preferred with multiple statements are used.  (Note: the value of `autocommit`Mul is not relevant.)

   ```
   START TRANSACTION;
   SQL statement(s)
   COMMIT;
   ```
2. Multiple statements in a single transaction.  This is error-prone since you can forget to issue the COMMIT:

   ```
   ((autocommit is OFF))
   SQL statement(s)
   COMMIT;
   ```
3. *Each* statement is its *own* transaction.  (Useful for casual usage where ACID is not needed.)

   ```
   ((autocommit is ON))
   SQL statement
   SQL statement
   SQL statement
   ((no COMMIT))
   ```

I don't know the mapping of these to python, but it seems to disagree with the Answer by Eugene and Comment by Cody.

Comment: Hi there is a MySQLConnection.in_transaction property  to indicate whether a transaction is active for the connection, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-in-transaction.html.  I have tested it to confirm it is in a transaction.

Comment: I updated my code https://github.com/qiulang/mysql/blob/main/crash_test.py to verify that we are in transaction when the first sql run and not in transaction after commit, but in transaction again when the next sql run.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just to read data from database we don't require to set transactions (default transaction is REPEATABLE READ)
2. transaction are used when any write commands(update , insert and delete) and read command are used simultaneously.
3. MySQL connection autocommit default = False explicitly we need to commit or rollback a transaction.

When it comes to use of transaction they are four types of Isolation level:

READ UNCOMMITTED','READ COMMITTED','REPEATABLE READ', and 'SERIALIZABLE'

[reference to transactions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transaction-isolation-levels-dbms/)